# jquery ajax element.children.length not getting updated

Tags: jquery, ajax, updates

We are making this ajax call every 5 seconds with the intent of appending its content to an existing parent element. This parent element has a max of 25 elements so anything above that most be removed from the beginning of the parent element. Everything works as expected except for the console.log call we make to output the contentLength. The contentLength keeps increasing in size and yet it should be at 25. I assume this has something to do with the fact we are making an ajax call and the DOM length is "incorrect" at this point inside the ajax call. Am I doing something wrong? How can I get around this?

```
    AJS.$.ajax({
        url: "ajax.action?",
        success: function (data) { 

                            //Cleanup and insert into parent div
                var divID   = "#" + insertContentIntoDiv;
                var wrapped = AJS.$("<div>" + data + "</div>");
                AJS.$(wrapped).find('title').remove().end();
                wrapped     = AJS.$(wrapped).find('meta').remove().end();
                AJS.$(divID + " dt:last-child").after(wrapped.html().trim());

                //Remove any whitespace pre-pended to parent element
                cleanWhiteSpaceFromElement(insertContentIntoDiv);

                //Remove child elements starting at beginning
                var parentElement = document.getElementById(insertContentIntoDiv);
                if(parentElement){

                    var contentLength = parentElement.childNodes.length;

                    console.log("________________cont: " + contentLength);
                    if(contentLength > 0){

                        var difference = contentLength - maxDisplayedLines;
                        console.log("___________removing: " + difference);
                        if(difference > 0){
                            AJS.$(divID + " dt:lt(" + difference + ")").remove();
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("ElementID " + insertContentIntoDiv + " appears to have no children. Was this expected?");
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("ElementID " + insertContentIntoDiv + " NOT found. Log parsing will NOT be done");
                }
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });
```

Comment: It might be useful to note this call sits inside a    window.setInterval(function(){ ... }, 5000);.

Comment: Most likely you are adding more than just a dt to the list, then since you are only removing the dt, whatever is left counts toward the contentLength, thus making it get larger and larger with each iteration. Use Inspect Element with chrome or firebug to see if there are any extra nodes.

Comment: ONLY adding dt's. What is funny is that the parent-element/container on the UI side is getting updated as expected but inspecting the length of the children it would appear that all the dt elements are still present. So visually it works as expected but in the backend the children-array-list is getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: Are you sure there's no lingering textNodes in there?

Comment: compare you current `contentLength` with `$(parentElement).children().length` if they are different, then you have lingering nodes that aren't elements, such as text nodes. If they are the same, then you have lingering elements.

Comment: They are exactly the same. How do I remove the lingering elements?

Comment: NO lingering text nodes. It's as if the html ONLY is getting updated and NOT the dom.

Comment: What does `$(parentElement).contents().length` give you? If it's greater than contentLength, iterate over it with $.each and log each one to see them all. If they're the same, then something else is going on and you're right, no lingering nodes.

Comment: All of the below calls return the same:

console.log("length: " + AJS.$(parentElement).children().size());

console.log("node-leng: " + parentElement.childNodes.length);

console.log("child-leng: " + parentElement.children.length);

console.log("cont-leng: " + AJS.$(parentElement).contents().length);

Comment: Another point of reference ... placing those calls just above the element-removal outputs all the same values but constantly increasing, while placing them just after the element-removal I get all 25's which is exactly what I would expect. The before scenario is increasing by exactly the same amount of children that I am adding but never decreasing.

Comment: The div I am adding/removing dt's too looks exactly like this:

`<div>
   <dt>hello</dt>
   <dt>world</dt>
 </div>`

Comment: Are those in a dl? can a dl have divs as direct children?

Comment: Yes. You can actually ignore the "<div>" and replace with "<dl>...</dl>" as that's what I meant to write.

Comment: For all those that came I here to help I humbly apologize. The problem came from code, that has worked, and so was expected to work, but was changed and so affected the number of lines being sent back from the server.